# Как обработать NPE если меня устраивает переменная null?

Tags: android, исключения, null

```
@Override
    public void loadUserData() {
        getView().updateUserInfo(
                mCurrentUser.getPhotoUrl().toString(), //здесь иногда прилетает null
                mCurrentUser.getDisplayName(),
                mCurrentUser.getEmail());
    }
```

Есть вот такой метод! В нем когда я получаю ссылку на фото может быть null! В целом меня такой вариант устраивает, я просто проверяю в другом методе на null эту ссылку и если она все же null то просто не загружаю картинку. Но приложение у меня падает и я не могу понять как мне решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
try {
      getView().updateUserInfo(
                mCurrentUser.getPhotoUrl().toString(),
                mCurrentUser.getDisplayName(),
                mCurrentUser.getEmail());
} catch (NullPointerExeption ignored){
}
```

Имя `ignored`нужно для того, чтобы IDE не показывало предупреждение "пустое тело `catch`". Можно в тело `catch` добавить обработку в случае NPE.

Comment: Точно. Чет сам не догадался. Спасибо)))